# replace pattern with a specific string with command like sed

Tags: python, unix, sed

Let's assume that I have a file.txt with content:
/c/csv/alex/alex/partition.csv

I don't know exactly what it's written there but I know what the pattern is:

```
csv/*/*.partition.csv
```

'*' - is a wildcard pattern

I tried it but it didn't change the content.

```
sed -i 's|csv/\*/\*.partition.csv|csv/top/top.partition.csv|g' file.txt
```

Do you have any idea ?

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: Regular expressions are quite different from shell "wildcard" patterns.

Answer (score 2):

You might use

```
sed -i 's|csv/.*/partition\.csv|csv/top/top.partition.csv|g' file.txt
```

The first part matches

- `csv/` Match l iterally
- `.*/` Match the rest of the line and the last occurrence of `/`
- `partition\.csv` Match partition.csv

**Note** to escape the dot to match it literarally

The contents after replacement in *file.txt*

```
/c/csv/top/top.partition.csv
```